# Can JQuery Mobile detect phone buttons like home and back?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Android phones have a home and back button.  I want to intercept these buttons in my application, where I'm using a webview and local jquery&jquery mobile.

JQuery Mobile can add a back button by default, but that is mimicking the browser back button and not what I want.  The back button on the android phone is doing something completely different than the webview "back".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is one of the best first questions I've seen here. A good brief description and it is clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No those button aren't sent to the browser

Answer (score 1):

Only in a PhoneGap application will these buttons be evented and able to be directly linked to your own jscript events...

Comment: PhoneGap would be the right thing to use in this situation. You can read about it here: [link](http://phonegap.com)

Answer (score 0):

Browser Back Button Detection, BY: BROOKE BRYAN

http://www.bajb.net/2010/02/browser-back-button-detection/